# Preinstalled Windows 8 UEFI is not able to get Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: uefi

I just bought a new Toshiba Satellite M840 with preloaded Windows 8. I checked that Windows is installed in UEFI mode.

I did a lot of research online on how to get Ubuntu 12.10 installed for dual boot.

First, I xhanged the BIOS settings from quick boot to normal and disabled Secure Boot.

I installed EaseUS Partition Master 9.2.1 and created a 64GB partition (NTFS), I called this partition F drive.

I also downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit DVD iso. In Windows 8 desktop mode, I launched Ubuntu Studio 12.10 and installed Ubuntu on this F drive. The installation went all the way to the end without a problem. When the Ubuntu installation was done, I rebooted.

After reboot, the problem appears. I can see a light blue display, showing Windows 8 and Ubuntu. When I selected Ubuntu, it popped up with another screen showing:

```
Windows fails to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. 
To fix the problem:
 1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer.
 2. Choose your language setting, and then click Next
 3. Click Repair your computer.
If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer 
manufacturer for assistance.

File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
status: 0xc000007b
Info: The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required 
file is missing or contains errors.
```

When I power off/on again, if I select Windows 8 (light blue screen, OS selection) the system will still boot up Windows 8 without a problem. The problem is that I am not able to boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you used WUBI with the installation, as:

1. You said that you installed it from Windows.
2. `\ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr` is a very common file in WUBI installations *(also look at the name!)*.

The problem is that **WUBI doesn't work with Windows 8**. Also, your Toshiba boots with UEFI, and **WUBI doesn't work with UEFI**. So you have the perfect combination to have a failed installation of Ubuntu.

How can you install it, then? First uninstall Ubuntu from Windows' Control Panel (the old one). Now follow this guide so you can install a working version of Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI